# Is every simply connected finite complex the classifying space of a finite monoid

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, semigroups-and-monoids, classifying-spaces, simplicial-complexes

On page 323 of [Fiedorowicz, "Classifying Spaces of Topological Monoids and Categories"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2374307?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) it was stated that "it seems likely that any *finite* simply connected complex should [have the same weak homotopy type as] the classifying space of a *finite* monoid." The paper was published in 1984. Has any progress been made in the last 30 years that would allow us to replace "it seems likely" by "it is known"?

Comment: Just writing to point out that every path-connected space has the weak homotopy type of $BM$ for some finite monoid $M$. This is a celebrated result of McDuff from 1979.

Comment: @Vidit Nanda: it seems you wanted to write "for some *discrete* monoid".

Comment: @BS You're absolutely correct, I definitely wanted to write discrete monoid.

Comment: @ViditNanda Thanks for your comments! Yes, what I wanted was finite (discrete) monoid not just discrete monoid. Simply connectedness is important, since, for example, there's no finite monoid whose classifying space has the weak homotopy type of $S^1$.